# chrome.hid.getDevices() typeError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hid

I use this"https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/hid " The following error occurred

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDevices' of undefined
    at enumerateDevices (control-panel.js:55)
    at initializeWindow (control-panel.js:42)

Is the chrome version a new issue? How do I modify it to use the new chrome?

```
var enumerateDevices = function() {
    chrome.hid.getDevices({}, onDevicesEnumerated);
    chrome.hid.onDeviceAdded.addListener(onDeviceAdded);
    chrome.hid.onDeviceRemoved.addListener(onDeviceRemoved);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You did install this repo as a browser-extension right?

Comment: Sorry,I don't know much about this language.How do I install this repo as a browser-extension ?

Comment: Well the simplest is probably by using the link to chrome webstore: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ohndmecdhlgohpibepbboddcoecomnpc

Comment: use this, my computer can't caught any device.

Comment: And you saw the note there "Note that in order to use this sample, you will need to update the usbDevices list in manifest.json with one or more VID/PID pairs corresponding to your hardware of choice."